# HTML form data view in jquery dased popup window

Tags: jquery, html, codeigniter

here is my form in view,I need to display this form data in a popup window when I click the submit button,I'd prefer do with jquery,I have search some methods but I couldn't find proper method to get popup window with form data.
   **I need first I fill the form, then when I click the submit button it should display form with filled data in a jquery window **

```
<body>
<link rel="stylesheet"    href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"     type="text/css" media="all" />  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://static.jquery.com/ui/css/demo-docs-   theme/ui.theme.css" type="text/   css" media="all" />  
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"   type="text/javascript"></script>  
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/jquery-ui.min.js"   type="text/javascript"></script>  
    <link rel="stylesheet"   href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-   ui.css">      
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <script>
    $(function() {
      $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy" });
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
/*$(function(){
    $("#birds").autocomplete({
      minLength: 3,
      source: "<?php //echo site_url('birds/get_birds'); ?>", // path to the get_birds    method
      select: function( event, ui ) {
            $('#test').val(ui.item.label);
            alert(ui.item.value+" : "+ ui.item.label +":"+ ui.item.city+":"+    ui.item.location);




      }
    });
 });*/
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var ac_config = {
        source: "<?php echo site_url('birds/get_birds'); ?>",
        select:function(event, ui){
            $("#address").val(ui.item.location);
        },
        minLength:2
    };
    $("#name").autocomplete(ac_config);
})
 </script>

 <div id="content">

<form action="#" method="post">
    <p>name: <input type="text" id="name"/></p>
    <p>address: <input type="text" id="address"/></p>
    <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"/></p>
    <input type="text" id="test" />
    <input type="submit" value="next">
    </form>

   </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by pop up window a new browser window that pops up or javascript based modal or something

Comment: I have edit question, I need javascript based window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div id="dialogbox"></div>

<div id="content">
    <p>name: <input type="text" id="name"/></p>
    <p>address: <input type="text" id="address"/></p>
    <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"/></p>
    <input type="text" id="test" />
 </div>
  <input type="submit" id="mybutt" value="next">
```

JQuery

```
$("#dialogbox").dialog({
    autoOpen:false,
    modal:true,
    title: "Use of Open event",
    width:400,
    open: function( event, ui ) {
    }
});

$('#mybutt').click(function() {
    $('#dialogbox').empty()
    var $clone=$("#content").clone()
    $('#dialogbox').append($clone)
    $("#dialogbox :input").prop("disabled", true);
    $('#dialogbox').dialog('open');
});
```

[SEE DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Y7s26/)

Comment: If you have any problem in the above code.Feel free to ask

Comment: when I click the submit button, just blink the window and disappear it suddenly

Comment: But in my fiddle it is working fine.Share your fiddle link where it is showing problem.

Comment: open http://jsfiddle.net/ .Put yout HTML content in HTML section and javascript in javascript section. Put only the required one. In framework and extension dropdown on the left corner select the library that you want to add. Run and save it and post the URL that u have got

Comment: problem is because of submit button .Actually we are doing two thing on submit button . opening a dialog as well as form action. So better make a button in which you want to open dialog outside form.SEE http://jsfiddle.net/f466a/

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <form action="#" method="post">
        <p>name:
            <input type="text" id="name" />
        </p>
        <p>address:
            <input type="text" id="address" />
        </p>
        <p>Date:
            <input type="text" id="datepicker" />
        </p>
        <input type="text" id="test" />
        <input type="submit" value="next">
    </form>
</div>

    <button id="showForm">Show Form</button>
```

**jQueryUI**:

```
$("#showForm").click(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog();
});
```

[JSFIDDLEDEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/w8893/)

Comment: I need first I fill the form, then when I click the submit button it should display form with filled data in a jquery window

Comment: man get the idea from this and try to do it yourself. Stackoverflow is not a code writing service

Comment: yeah I know.when I click button appear window and suddenly disappear